# Como substituir o seletor * em produção

Tags: css, css3

Então, ao usar o seletor * para fazer o reset do **margin|padding** geral do **HTML** o CSSLint aponta que em produção pode dar gargalo para o usuário.

```
*{ 
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
```

Para mim a "solução" que me vem é:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Mas, não é basicamente a mesma coisa? Eu realmente não sei porque, mas dessa maneira o CSS Lint não aponta possíveis problemas de performance. Existe alguma função para fazer isso? ou maneira melhor? Agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seletores universais como `*, [disabled]`, `[type=“text”]`, etc. são muito caros para o navegador para corresponder, como cada elemento no DOM deve ser verificada.

O seletor universal é usado frequentemente para `box-sizing` e outros globals. No entanto, muitas vezes isso pode ser otimizado pelo agrupamento de elementos relevantes. Veja solução de dimensionamento.

```
    html, body, div, article, section, main, footer, header, form, fieldset, legend,
    pre, code, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, textarea,
    input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"],
    input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="url"], .border-box { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Veja mais aqui https://github.com/tachyons-css/tachyons-box-sizing